# Cannot detect ttyS0 in python RPi3b+

Tags: serial, pi-3b+, python-2.x

I'm using the Rpi 3B+ and understand the hardware uart is used by the bluetooth.
I'm OK to use the other uart

I've followed several threads and believed I've done all I can.

1. Enabled the Uart in config.ini
2. Set the 'core_freq=250'
3. Disabled the Console in cmdline.txt

   (I've double checked using the config tool)

This command shows the serial ports

```
ls -l /dev/ttyS0 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

.. and shows

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64 Feb 28 14:17 /dev/ttyAMA0
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 64 Feb 28 14:17 /dev/ttyS0
```

But this python command only shows one port.

```
python -m serial.tools.list_ports -v

/dev/ttyAMA0
    desc: ttyAMA0
    hwid: 3f201000.serial
1 ports found
```

What am I missing here.. ( inexperienced user )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undo everything you did and enable serial in `raspi-config`.

Write to `/dev/serial0` (which is the default serial port).

PS I tried the `python -m serial.tools.list_ports -v` you listed.

It only shows 1 port, as you stated, despite my Pi being correctly configured with a serial port. The fault seems to be with the tool you used - nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: After I did all what I previously typed.. I did go to raspi config, I saw your other post suggesting that. What I saw was the uart enabled and the console disabled. I assumed that it was therefore done correctly.
I see two serial ports with one command, and one serial port with the python command.
I don't know why that is or the relevance, as if the bash command sees two ports but the python function doesn't. Accept that I may not know what I'm talking about. ;)

Comment: I presume you are referring to [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 , Pi3B+, PiZeroW](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) - the Foundation finally "fixed" this a year later. You can still use the error-prone multi-step process, but the post was updated to explain the simpler, more future-proof option.